# Get singleflight.Group.Do to retry

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm trying to cache requests using singleflight which works out of the box.

I want to go one further and subsequently retry failed (errored requests) for the same key.
For that i'm making a call to group.Forget(Key).
But subsequent calls just seem to reuse the prior result and not retry.

```golang
type Result struct {
    v int
    k string
}

var group singleflight.Group

// see https://encore.dev/blog/advanced-go-concurrency
func main() {

    if true {
        for k := 0; k <= 2; k++ {
            go doGroup(context.Background(), "sameKey")
        }

        <-time.Tick(5 * time.Second)

        for k := 0; k <= 3; k++ {
            go doGroup(context.Background(), "sameKey")
        }

        <-time.Tick(30 * time.Second)
    }

}
func doGroup(ctx context.Context, key string) (*Result, error) {

    log.Println("Inside normal call")

    results, err, shared := group.Do(key, func() (interface{}, error) {
        r, e := doExpensive(ctx, key)

        // Do this; so if it encountered an error;
        // subsequent calls will retry
        // didnt work
        // perhaps because of timing
        if e != nil {
            group.Forget(key)
        }

        return r, e
    })

    fmt.Printf("Call to multiple callers: %v\n", shared)
    // does not retry if error occured

    if err != nil {
        wrapped := fmt.Errorf("error bruh %s: %w", key, err)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", wrapped.Error())
        return nil, wrapped
    }

    fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", results)

    return results.(*Result), err
}

func doExpensive(ctx context.Context, key string) (*Result, error) {
    log.Printf("Inside Expensive function with key %s\n", key)
    <-time.Tick(time.Second * 10)

    dice := rand.Int31n(10)

    if true {
        // <-time.Tick(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(dice*100))
        return nil, errors.New("operation failed")
    }

    <-time.Tick(time.Second * time.Duration(dice))
    return &Result{
        v: int(dice),
        k: key,
    }, nil
}
```

I've simulated waits between calls to doGroup so the key is actually forgotten by the second call.
But the doExpensive function only seems to ever be called once.

A reproduction of my code can be found here

https://go.dev/play/p/psGjFTypU6C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is combination of timing and behaviour of `Forget` method. As it is *somewhat* stated in the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight#Group.Forget):

> Forget tells the singleflight to forget about a key. *Future* calls to Do for this key will call the function rather than waiting for an earlier call to complete.

And *Future* there means all the calls to `group.Do` happened *after* the call to `group.Forget`. In your example all the calls to `group.Do` happened *before* the call of `group.Forget`, and all of them got the result of the first failed call. Possible approach is to do trigger retries outside of the `group.Do call. Something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/sync/singleflight"
)

type Result struct {
    v int
    k string
}

var group singleflight.Group

func main() {
    for k := 0; k <= 2; k++ {
        go doGroup(context.Background(), "sameKey")
    }

    <-time.Tick(5 * time.Second)

    for k := 0; k <= 3; k++ {
        go doGroup(context.Background(), "sameKey")
    }

    <-time.Tick(30 * time.Second)
}

func doGroup(ctx context.Context, key string) (*Result, error) {
    log.Println("Inside normal call")

    for {
        results, err, shared := group.Do(key, func() (interface{}, error) {
            return doExpensive(ctx, key)
        })

        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Normal call error: %s. Will retry \n", err)
            continue
        }

        log.Printf("Normal call results: %v [shared=%v]\n", results, shared)

        return results.(*Result), err
    }
}

var returnedFirstErr atomic.Bool

func doExpensive(ctx context.Context, key string) (r *Result, e error) {
    log.Printf("Inside Expensive function with key %s\n", key)
    defer func() {
        log.Printf("Result of Expensive function: [%v, %s] for %s\n", r, e, key)
    }()
    <-time.Tick(time.Second * 10)

    dice := rand.Int31n(10)

    if !returnedFirstErr.Load() {
        returnedFirstErr.Store(true)
        return nil, errors.New("operation failed")
    }

    return &Result{
        v: int(dice),
        k: key,
    }, nil
}
```

Side question. Are you sure behavior of `singleflight` is what you need, maybe you should use [sync.Once](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Once) instead? In case of `singleflight` you prevent multiple calls from happening at the same time, i.e. calls which done later in time are still executed. In case of `sync.Once` the call is done exactly once in the lifetime of process

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help. One more side note. Try avoiding [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) when asking a question.

Comment: Thanks. I guess in this case I really wanted to implement a retry with singleflight 